# spring boot 2 datasource schema is not my oracle schema initialize schema

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I want to use the datasource schema defined in the properties in spring boot 2.
It is a oracle db, there the schema is the user. So the getSchema() methode is useless for me.

Is there some sql init command, so i can put there something like
"ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = MY_SCHEMA" ?

I tried some but nothing worked.

Comment: give your oracle db configuration and properties file

Answer (score 0):

I have my datasource completly filled in the properties like user url and schema. But if I use the getschema() I get the user. In oracle db the schema is not  equal the schema, We know from other dbms.